# Control the edittext contents in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, logic

I have some edittext for getting some integer numbers.
Now I want to control their contents. e.g. if the written number is between 1 and 22 do something.

How do I get texts from editText and convert them into int to compare them?

Comment: When should it happen? After clicking a button?

Comment: yes ! exactly,  I forget to write it

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside your buttons' onClickListener:

```
try {
   int number = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
   if(number >= 1 && number < 22) {
      // do smth
   }
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Could not convert text into integer");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but why you write number!=null, number is integer not boolean?

Comment: It's always good to check for null pointers. :) But in this case you're right. Any String except of numbers is invalid and will throw NumberFormatException. i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your button is `btn` and editText is `edt` then do following

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
        int a;
        a=Integer.parseInt(edt.getText().toString());

        if(a>1 && a<22)
        {
           //do something here
        }
         }
       });
```

Comment: Yes. `a` is the integer value @MinaDahesh

Answer (score 0):

Use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(check){
                 //do stuff
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
```

and in your myTextWatcher

```
TextWatcher myTextWatcher= new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          if(Integer.parseInt(s)>1 && Integer.parseInt(s)<=22)
          {
             // perform you action
          }
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    };
```